add network route with higher priority than wifi on windows
I'm trying to configure the following:

General access to internet - via WiFi
Access to specific internet IPs - via USB Tethering on mobile phone

I run command ...
route add 123.123.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.42.106 metric 1
... with the expectation of that route to get higher priority than WiFi network - thus achieving the goal 'Access to specific internet IPs via USB Tethering on mobile phone', but it gets `metric of mobile network + 1' and actually that route is ignored because WiFi has higher priority (tracert 123.123.123.1 starts at 192.168.0.1)
Here are the top lines of resulting route table (192.168.0.1 - WiFi network, 192.168.42.129 - Mobile network via USD tethering)
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.160      8
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.42.129   192.168.42.106     15
    123.123.123.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.42.106     16
  123.123.123.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.42.106    271
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

Q: Why route at line 3 gets metric=16 and not metric=1 as I expect?
Q: Probably there is better/simpler way to achieve my goals?

Are you sure you wanted to specify the machine as its own gateway?
